# Adding HTML to a page with a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Okay Here's what I want my extension to do. I want it to add some HTML to a page (Label, button whatever).

Here's What I have...

content.js (it actually tries to add a label not a button)

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "addButton") {
        addButtonHTML();
    }
});


function addButtonHTML() {
    $('body').append("<label>HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH</label>");

}
```

background.js

```
addButton("addButton");

function addButton(action) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {
            action: action,
            tabid: tab.id
        }, function(response) {});
    });
}
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong? and what should my manifest look like this is what I have as of now.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Does Stuff",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon-19.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "48": "icon-48.png",
        "128": "icon-128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you want a page action (only on some pages, executes when you click the icon in the omnibox), or a content script (on all matching pages, happens at page load)?

Comment: I only want it to happen on certain pages. I will be determining which pages in background.js

Comment: Can someone show me a simple example of adding a button to a page? I've read the documentation that google offers but none have solved my problem.

Comment: Could your problem be that `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` is deprecated, and you need `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`?

Answer (score 1):

You indicated that you only want this on certain pages which you determine in `background.js`.  This means you can remove the content script from your manifest, and I think you will also be able to change the `tabs` permission to [`activeTab`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html).  There is still the question of whether the label should always be loaded on these pages, or only after a user action.

If the label should always be there, you want `background.js` (which will run on every page load) to call `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to load `content.js` ([reference](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi)), which no longer needs the listener that you added.

If the label should appear as the result of a user action, this sounds like you want a [page action](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction).  In addition to the above, `background.js` should call `chrome.pageAction.show(tabId)` to show the page action icon, and use `chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(loadScriptFunction)` to call `executeScript`.

---

**Edit:** I think I was able to finally diagnose where your attempt went wrong.  Google doesn't specify when `background.js` executes, but it seems to be rarely (extension startup?), and definitely not after `content.js`.  If you wrap your bare `addButton("addButton")` inside of a `chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener`, then it appears to work.

Comment: I am using the chrome declaritiveContent to determine certain rules with my extension. In this case I am determining which pages to show a pageaction icon and once I figure out how, inject the label on that page. The label will always be loaded no user action is needed. The only condition for the label to be injected is if the tab is on a certain page.

Comment: If you can simplify your rules to just the urls of the appropriate pages, then you could use the `content_scripts.matches` entry in your manifest to include `content.js`, and eliminate the need for `background.js` entirely.